# How to post Video with custom thumbnail picture using RestFB?

Tags: java, restfb

I can publish video with description using RestFB. I want to add thumbnail picture to video. How can I do that?

I tried to add some Parameter when publish as

```
Parameter.with("thumb", BinaryAttachment.with(fileName, fetchBytesFromImage(fileName)))
Parameter.with("picture", BinaryAttachment.with(fileName, fetchBytesFromImage(fileName)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If publishing more than one `BinaryAttachment`, you have to add the `fieldname` to the `BinaryAttachment.with` method , put both `BinaryAttachments` in a `List` and use it in the publish method.

It looks like this:

```
fbClient.publish("me/videos", GraphResponse.class,
      Arrays.asList(
          BinaryAttachment.with("source","1.mp4",inputstream), 
          BinaryAttachment.with("thumb", "bla.jpg", fetchBytesFromImage("bla.jpg"))),
      Parameter.with("description", "Test Thumb"));
```